# Springboot + Spring Cache Abstraction (Lettuce) + APM (AppDynamics)

Tags: spring-boot, redis, lettuce, appdynamics, apm

I have an app built with SpringBoot and Spring Cache Abstraction, using Redis through Lettuce.
I need to monitor via APM AppDynamics tool, but by default it only gets data from Jedis.
I can create an exit point in AppDynamics, but I need to know exactly which class and method is responsible for opening the connection and executing commands to REDIS.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create Custom Exit Points to collect metrics/data.

Go to your Controller:
Remote Services > Configure > Your or Tier > Custom Exit Points > Add

And create 2 Custom Exit Points, like below:

```
Name: REDIS GET (Lettuce)
Type: Cache
Is High Volume: true
Class [with a Class Name that] equals: io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisAsyncCommands
Method Name: get
```

```
Name: REDIS SET (Lettuce)
Type: Cache
Is High Volume: true
Class [with a Class Name that] equals: io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisAsyncCommands
Method Name: set
```

[image]

[image]

Make some requests and wait a few moments.... and voilá!
[image]